# AWK failing to sum floats

Tags: awk

I am trying to sum the last 12 values in a field in a particular csv file, but AWK is failing to correctly sum the values. If I output the data to a new file then run the same AWK statement against the new file it works.

Here are the contents of the original file. The fields are separated by ";"
I want to sum the values in the 3rd field

```
...$ tail -12 OriginalFile.csv...

02/02/2020 10:30:00;50727.421;0.264;55772.084;0.360;57110.502;0.384
02/02/2020 10:35:00;50727.455;0.408;55772.126;0.504;57110.548;0.552
02/02/2020 10:40:00;50727.489;0.408;55772.168;0.504;57110.593;0.540
02/02/2020 10:45:00;50727.506;0.204;55772.193;0.300;57110.621;0.336
02/02/2020 10:50:00;50727.541;0.420;55772.236;0.516;57110.667;0.552
02/02/2020 10:55:00;50727.566;0.300;55772.269;0.396;57110.703;0.432
02/02/2020 11:00:00;50727.590;0.288;55772.300;0.372;57110.737;0.408
02/02/2020 11:05:00;50727.605;0.180;55772.321;0.252;57110.762;0.300
02/02/2020 11:10:00;50727.621;0.192;55772.344;0.276;57110.786;0.288
02/02/2020 11:15:00;50727.659;0.456;55772.389;0.540;57110.835;0.588
02/02/2020 11:20:00;50727.681;0.264;55772.417;0.336;57110.866;0.372
02/02/2020 11:25:00;50727.704;0.276;55772.448;0.372;57110.900;0.408
```

I used the following code to print the original value and the summed value of field 3 for each record, but it just returns the same output for the summed value for each line

```
...$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";" } ; { sum += $3 } { print $3, sum }' OriginalFile.csv|tail -12...

0.264 2.00198e+09
0.408 2.00198e+09
0.408 2.00198e+09
0.204 2.00198e+09
0.420 2.00198e+09
0.300 2.00198e+09
0.288 2.00198e+09
0.180 2.00198e+09
0.192 2.00198e+09
0.456 2.00198e+09
0.264 2.00198e+09
0.276 2.00198e+09
```

If I output the contents of the file into a different file, the same code works as expected

```
...$ tail -12 OriginalFile.csv > testfile2.csv...

...$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";" } ; { sum += $3 } { print $3, sum }' testfile2.csv...

0.264 0.264
0.408 0.672
0.408 1.08
0.204 1.284
0.420 1.704
0.300 2.004
0.288 2.292
0.180 2.472
0.192 2.664
0.456 3.12
0.264 3.384
0.276 3.66
```

How can I get the correct output from the original file without having to create a new file?

Comment: If you want just the last 12 lines fed to awk, why are you putting the tail at the end of the pipeline and not the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shawn's excellent comment points out, the order in which you pipe in your data is the problem. By the time you reach the 12th line from the end, `sum` is already `2.00198e+09`; adding many small fractions is not significant, so it seems like it is "*the same output*".

Simply:

```
tail -12 OriginalFile.csv | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";" } ; { sum += $3 } { print $3, sum }'
```